# i want to put border around my video player in html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

when add a border to it , the video player overlaps the border

i got like this 
[image]

but i want like
[image]

my entire code available here: https://codesandbox.io/s/ominiassesment-ike26?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You're required to put the relevant code here, in your question. Links to other sites don't qualify.

Comment: Also, this isn't a React question. It's merely CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.media-box {
  ...
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0, 0.75);
  border-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ominiassesment-yix0k?file=/src/styles.css)

Answer (score 2):

You need `overflow: hidden;` on your `.media-box`

```
.media-box {
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 80px 80px 80px rgba(6, 6, 7, 0.2);
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and see if it works:

```
.media-box .video-react {
  border: 4px solid red; // You can change this according to your need
}
```